# Pydantic model with data type field. Can't use Union, Optional, List

Tags: python, python-typing, pydantic

I'm using pydantic in my project and defined a model with Type field.

```py
from typing import Type, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Item(BaseModel):
    data_type: Type
```

Works well with standard library types (bool, int, str etc), but when I try to create an instance using for example Union, Optional or List from typing module:

```py
it = Item(data_type=Union[int, str])
```

I get an error:

```
File "pydantic/main.py", line 362, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Item
data_type
  a class is expected (type=type_error.class)
```

How can I define data_type field for Union, Optional and List types?

Comment: I think this is impossible because generic built-in classes, like `List`, `Dict`, `Union`, and so on, cannot be instantiated. I can suggest use [typevar](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#typevar) `T = TypeVar("T")` instead of `Type`, but this is essentially equivalent of `Any`